# Proof that, for finite $a$, $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x) = -\infty$ implies $\lim_{x\to a^-} f'(x) = -\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

So this is just a conjecture. It might be true as is, but it also might need some further conditions, as a clever manipulation of $\sin(1/x)$ or something could break it (I haven't found a counterexample, I guess that too is a conjecture).

Intuitively, it makes sense: if a graph goes downward in a sort of vertical asymptote, then the line tangent to the graph will get closer and closer to vertical in the negative direction (that was less than eloquent, but I hope it was clear).

I don't know how to prove the implication. There is very little to work with. I have tried manipulating $\lim_{x\to a^-} f'(x)$ using the limit definition of a derivative, but that gets us nowhere.

Comment: What you can prove using the fundamental theorem of calculus is that $\liminf_{x\rightarrow a^-} f'(x)=-\infty$. However, in general the limit will not exist.

Comment: What about something like $\frac{1}{x}+\sin(\frac{1}{x})$?

Comment: The problem is even though $f$ itself might go to $-\infty$, it doesn't even guarantee that $f'$ be negative for any small neigborhodd around $a$. It might be that it is infinitely wriggling around $a$ but nevertheless $f(x)$ does go to $-\infty$

Comment: @user160738 You're right... what condition can we set that prohibits infinite wriggling?

Comment: @recursiverecursion I think assuming that $f'$ is decreasing in some interval $(a-\epsilon,a)$ would make this statement true. If $f'$ was bounded below by ,say $M<0$, then this condition ensures that graph of $f$ lies above that of linear function with gradient $M$ passing through $(a-\epsilon,f(a-\epsilon))$, which obviously is contradictory to assumption on $f$

Answer (score 8):

Here's a counterexample: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}+\sin{\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)}$. Clearly this tends to $-\infty$ as $x \uparrow 0$. Its derivative is
$$ f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2}\cos{\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)} = -\frac{1}{x^2}\cos^2{\left( \frac{1}{2x} \right)} $$
using the double-angle formula $\cos{2A}=\cos^2{A}-1$. But $\cos{(1/(2x))}$ has infinitely many zeros in any interval $(-\varepsilon, 0)$, so we cannot have $f'(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: You beat my comment by 11 seconds (+1)

Comment: More points for an answer.

Comment: Wow, that's really clever! Is there any further condition we can impose to make the conclusion true (ie a condition that makes functions like this "illegal")?

Comment: i think somehting like $-e^{-x^2} $also breaks it

Comment: @Faust7 You mean $-e^{-1/x^2}$?

Comment: Sorry yes. thats what i meant.